# how to use the segbot package for navigation?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Could anyone know how to use the segbot package (https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot) for navigation?

Currently what I can think is that the following three, but I don't know how to combine this segbot package with the navigation package (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation)

1. git clone https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot
2. catkin_make in the catkin_ws folder
3. roslaunch segbot.launch

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92106/how-to-use-the-segbot-package-for-navigation?/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going to assume you are talking about autonomous navigation here. If you want to setup your navigation configuration, take a look at the documentation on this page: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation

You can also take a look at how we do navigation using the segbot stack in the segbot_navigation package: https://github.com/utexas-bwi/segbot_apps

Between the documentation on navigation and our implementation inside segbot_navigation, I am hopeful that you will figure out the navigation configuration required to run your robot.

You can also try using segbot_navigation directly, with the following caveats:

1. It is designed for ros hydro
2. The ABI is unstable and still changed frequently. It should stabilize by the end of year.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0